# How to protect each sub directory of the SVN repository by using the Apache HTTP?

Tags: apache, svn, ldap

I've achieved to protect each SVN repository by using Apache HTTP, mod_authnz_ldap as the following: -

```
<Location /svn/myProject/>
    ...
    Require ldap-group some-group
</Location>
```

Anyhow I would like to protect some sub directories under myProject e.g.

```
<Location /svn/myProject/document>
    ...
    Require ldap-group sa-group
</Location>

<Location /svn/myProject/code>
    ...
    Require ldap-group dev-group
</Location>
```

Please note, the project root and other sub directories are allowed for all team member.

```
<Location /svn/myProject/>
    ...
    Require ldap-group sa-group
    Require ldap-group dev-group
    Require ldap-group team-member-group
</Location>
```

Regarding to the above configuration, I cannot protect the team-member-group to access the code and document. I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong and would like your help to shed some light to me. Thank you very much for your help in advance. I'm looking forward to hearing from you soon.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid, you'll have more troubles, than now, on your way

I never tried, heard and can't predict results of overloading `<location>` **below** SVN-WebDAV location (usually they are served from root-definitions)

In order to clarify (for me)

- is myProject: single repository, parent-dir of repositories tree (how you define SVN-locations in Aapache: separate location for each repo with SVNPath or common base with SVNParenPath)?
- can you accept and use "mixed" solution with hand-work - path-based authorization by mod_authz_svn for groups, prepared from LDAP-groups?

Maybe, due to SVN-specific limitation, you will not be able to use mod_authnz_ldap for Authorization Phase, only for Authentication Phase - all (known by me) sources for Path-Based Authorization suggest using only mod_authz_svn

Maybe ["mod_authz_svn and AD group synchronization"](http://blogs.freebsdish.org/tmclaugh/2010/07/20/mod_authz_svn-and-ad-group-synchronization/) (result of fast-googling) blog-post will be useful for you

Comment: Hi, I'm using CSVN with configure as SVNParenPath and use the centralized Apache HTTP as a proxy to that CSVN. All authentication with LDAP is configured at the centralized. Anyhow I can accept any mixed and match solution for sure. At the moment I'm looking and learning from your link.

Answer (score 1):

Normally we don't "protect" like this.

When using HTTP, we normally use mod_svn_authz, and configure the authorization file.  However the drawback according to your previous solution is we are not making use of ldap groups by default.  (I believe there should be some way to make use of ldap group in maintaining the authz file)

With svn authz file, it is straight-forward, with something like:

```
[/]
*=
@sa-group=rw
@dev-group=rw
@team-member-group=rw

[/doc]
*=
@sa-group=rw

[/code]
*=
@dev-group=rw
```

Comment: Hi, at the moment I'm looking and learning from your suggestion together with the link from Lazy Badger.